# How can I handle float number correctly in JS?

Tags: javascript, parsefloat

In JS, I do have a float number which come from php as below:

`var number = 2,206.00`

In JS, I need to use `parseFloat` that number.

So I tried `parseFloat(number)`, but its give only 2. So how can I get `2206.00` instead of 2?

Comment: `In JS, I do have a float number which come from php as below:` how is that `var number = 2,206.00` generated? (In PHP `,` is also an operator, and having `.00` for a float does also not make sense, so in PHP the number would also be  `2206` and not `2,206.00`.)

Comment: @t.niese, In php I used `number_format($myNumber, 2)`, thats why Its come like that way.

Comment: How is that complete `var number = 2,206.00` generated? Or how do you get the `2,206.00` form the PHP side and store it in `number`?

Comment: @t.niese, Its come as an ajax response

Comment: Ok, and then why do you convert it to a localized string using `number_format($myNumber, 2)` instead of passing it as a number directly? It seems as if you try to fix a problem on the JavaScript side that is a result of something done wrong on the PHP side.

Comment: In some places in my page, I need to display the number in that format

Comment: Ok, then apply that format at those places. But the data should be transferred without localization.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`Number.parseFloat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/parseFloat) is the same function object as [`globalThis.parseFloat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat).

If `globalThis.parseFloat` encounters a character other than:

- a plus sign or,
- a minus sign or,
- a decimal point or,
- an exponent (`E` or `e`)

...it returns the value up to that character, ignoring the invalid character and characters following it. A second decimal point also stops parsing.

So the following prints `2`. And this seems to be your problem.

```js
console.log(parseFloat('2,206.00')) // 2
```

Solution: use string manipulation to remove any commas from the number (really a [`String`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String) before parsing it.

```js
console.log(parseFloat('2,206.00'.replaceAll(',', ''))) // 2206
```

If you need to store the value as a number but render it as a formatted string, you may need [Number#toFixed](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed) to render the values after the decimal point:

```js
console.log((2206).toFixed(2)) // '2206.00'
```

Final note: be careful about localization because some countries use commas for decimal points and decimal points for number grouping. As @t.niese says: store number values without localization, and then apply localization at the surface of your app. But that is a wider, more complicated topic.

Answer (score 1):

You have to remove comma first and use `parseFloat`.

And about 2 decimal after dot, I see you use `number_format($myNumber, 2)` in PHP, so in JS, you use `.toFixed(2)`.

```js
var number = '2,206.00';
var result = parseFloat(number.replace(/,/g, '')).toFixed(2);
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all what you currently have most probably would trigger an Unexpected number error in JS.

It seems the generated value comes from the `number_format()` PHP function which returns a string. Moreover the `var number` variable should also be considered a string as we have a string format.

So firstly you should quote `var number = '2,206.00'` after that, you have to make the string float-like in order to parse it as float so we should replace `,` with empty string in order for the number to become `2206.00` `number = number.replace(",","")`. Lastly the parse should be done now in order to convert the float-like string to an actual float `parseFloat(number)`.

Whole code:

```
var number = '2,206.00';
number.replace(",","");
number = parseFloat(number);
```